# remove duplicate data in array with key and assoc

Tags: php, arrays

I have executed data from table in database and the results is

```
array(3) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
      [0]=> string(1) "1"
      ["id_pegawai"]=> string(1) "1"
      [1]=> string(1) "1"
      ["id_jabatan"]=> string(1) "1"
      [2]=> string(1) "1"
      ["id_media"]=> string(1) "1"
      [3]=> string(7) "Marjana"
      ["nama_pegawai"]=> string(7) "Marjana"
      [4]=> string(8) "NIK.0001"
      ["nik"]=> string(8) "NIK.0001"
   },
   [1]=>
   array(5) {
      [0]=> string(1) "2"
      ["id_pegawai"]=> string(1) "2"
      [1]=> string(1) "4"
      ["id_jabatan"]=> string(1) "4"
      [2]=> string(1) "8"
      ["id_media"]=> string(1) "8"
      [3]=> string(7) "Deny"
      ["nama_pegawai"]=> string(7) "Deny"
      [4]=> string(8) "NIK.0007"
      ["nik"]=> string(8) "NIK.0007"
   },
   [2]=>
   array(5) {
      [0]=> string(1) "3"
      ["id_pegawai"]=> string(1) "3"
      [1]=> string(1) "9"
      ["id_jabatan"]=> string(1) "9"
      [2]=> string(1) "6"
      ["id_media"]=> string(1) "6"
      [3]=> string(7) "Juny"
      ["nama_pegawai"]=> string(7) "Juny"
      [4]=> string(8) "NIK.0011"
      ["nik"]=> string(8) "NIK.0011"
   }
}
```

I want to change it like this:

```
array(3) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
      [0]=> string(1) "1"
      [1]=> string(1) "1"
      [2]=> string(1) "1"
      [3]=> string(7) "Marjana"
      [4]=> string(8) "NIK.0001"
   },
   [1]=>
   array(5) {
      [0]=> string(1) "2"
      [1]=> string(1) "4"
      [2]=> string(1) "8"
      [3]=> string(7) "Deny"
      [4]=> string(8) "NIK.0007"
   },
   [2]=>
   array(5) {
      [0]=> string(1) "3"
      [1]=> string(1) "9"
      [2]=> string(1) "6"
      [3]=> string(7) "Juny"
      [4]=> string(8) "NIK.0011"
   }
}
```

How to remove array with assoc ?
please help me, thank you

NOTE: I'M NOT USE MYSQL, BUT ORACLE.
and I'm executed query use code like this:

```
 $this->connection->executeQuery($sql, array($tanggalAwal, $tanggalAkhir), array(Type::DATETIME, Type::DATETIME))->fetchAll();
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), where are you stuck?

Comment: when you are extracting data from db at that time only take index array from db. It seems you are using some mvc framework

Answer (score 0):

I have feeling what you use `mysql_*`, so replace:

```
mysql_fetch_array()
```

with:

```
mysql_fetch_row()
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at [fetch_style](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) in `PDOStatement::fetch`
Or at [mysql_fetch_array](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) `result_type` option, if your still using the old & depreciated php-mysql.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

and try this code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

The key is `MYSQL_NUM`.

hope will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this issue before when I was design an php script about getting the results from database.

If you do not want to get the array values without mention key, you may use mysql_fetch_assoc().

For example:

```
     while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           var_dump($rows); 
           //You may using "var_dump" to check the results that correct or not
           //It's a simple and useful way instead of echo.
     }
```